# How to use 2 .Include<> methods to associate 3 tables

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I need to output information about article's tags (it is a many-to-many relationship and it's done) and about article's category (it is a one-to-many relationship) but I have some problems with it. In brief I can't use more than 2 Include <> like this (NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object):

```
Article article = await db.Articles.Include(ar=>ar.CategoryId).Include(a => a.ArticlesTags).ThenInclude(at => at.Tag).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
```

But this works properly but doesn't output category:

```
Article article = await db.Articles.Include(a => a.ArticlesTags).ThenInclude(at => at.Tag).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
```

This is my classes:

```
public class Article
{        
    public int Id {get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] HeroImage { get; set; }        
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }      

    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }  //implementing one to many relationship with category
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ArticleTag> ArticlesTags { get; set; } //implementing many to many relationship with tags
    public Article()
    {
        ArticlesTags = new List<ArticleTag>();
    }
}

 public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        Articles = new List<Article>();
    }
}
```

How can I use these methods to output both tags and category?

Comment: Your first query tries to include `CategoryId`.  Perhaps you meant to include `Category` instead?

Comment: What @SamAxe pointed out is probably your entire problem. You *can* use `Include` twice in the same call.

Comment: @SamAxe,yes,  it works! Ty! Can you give me some sourse to read more about relationship between tables and usage. I cannot see the difference between usage CategoryId and Catrgory :/

Comment: Category is a table, represented by a class in your code.  CategoryId is a column in the Category table, represented by a property on the Category class in code.